# Release a version in Jira using API

Tags: api, jira

I want to know if is it possible to release a version in Jira ?
How can I do this using Rest API ?

I've already read this : https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-to-release-a-version-using-REST-api/qaq-p/563559

But have there been any update?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This curl put request updates an existing version and tags as released

```
curl --location --request PUT 
'https://yourcompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/version/VERSION_ID' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YOUR_BASIC_AUTH' \
--data-raw '{
    "released": true
}'
```